# how to set one image to the center bottom on another background image

Tags: html, css, position, background-image

hello i'm trying to set one image to the center bottom on another background image.

image contain one (ktm)Bike background image and on that another image of car which is at center bottom). [image]

i have also tried background-position property as center bottom but still not working. i don't know how to do that. i have provided image in the comment box that what i'm exactly trying to make please refer that image don't ignore. and also provided my code what i have tried yet. please can anyone give show me example that how i do sorry but i'm really new to cascading style sheets. and do i need use to absolute property for that?

JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/vr50vza2/1

```css
.f4-pos {
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.footer {
  background-image: url("../images/footer.png");
}

.foot4 {
  background-image: url("../images/iauro-footer-logo.png");
}

.ban {
  height: 800px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.im3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.norep {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer ban norep">
  <div class="foot4 f4-pos im3 norep"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the image or codes in your question for better understanding of your problem

Comment: @Carl Jan Please refer this image for layout what i'm trying to make https://ibb.co/dHZqGF and this is my code what i have tried https://jsfiddle.net/vr50vza2/1/

Comment: Better if you put it in your question

Comment: i can't i'm newbie

Comment: please dont do negative marking i really need help i have provided all data as much as i can

Comment: Can you add iamges to ur jfiddle as well! it is trying to load image, but there are no image.

Comment: have you tried setting the inside image to position:absolute and set the position(top,left/right)?

Comment: yeah i have done but don''t know why that's not working please can you give me example how to do that i'm really newbie please help

Comment: Please update your jsfiddle, do not use ../images/footer.png, we cannot see the image. Instead, search for a sample image in google.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I removed some unnecessary css and the image, but you can return them later.

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.foot4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.ban {
  height: 500px;
}

.im3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer ban norep">
  <div class="foot4 f4-pos im3 norep"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can show me by using background images and also try to use background-size: center bottom property

Comment: I dont have images to spare, you could try it on your own, just remove the `background-color`, then add `background-image`. Is it really necessary to use `background-size: center bottom`?

Comment: is it possible to move this red block vertically. ? i want this block get moved from top so is it possible i have tried but not working. 
like suppose in this e.g- In foot4   class i want to make  float: 30%; top:40px;

Comment: HEY @Carl Jan Is It possible to move this block with any location(like any co-ordinates) on the background i want on that block in left side but with some margins and also space from top

Comment: Yes it can be moved anywhere inside its relatively positioned element

Answer (score 0):

Please Check out the FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/jw3dqb71/

```
.f4-pos
{
  position: absolute;
  background-position:center bottom;
}
.footer1
{
  background-image: url("http://pre09.deviantart.net/49b5/th/pre/i/2015/160/1/9/skies__backround_practice__by_darklatias61-d8wm1wr.png");
}
.foot4
{
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url("http://backgrounds.mysitemyway.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/watercolor-grunge-000100-glossy-rust.jpg");
    background-size:100%;

}
.ban
{
  height: 800px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
.im3
{
  height: 100px;
  width : 300px;
}
.norep
{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.footerWrap {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.footer {
    width:400px;
    margin:auto;
}
.footerContent {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px 0;
}
.footer p {float:left; width:100%; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: another image is not displaying in fiddle

Comment: which image?? footer image?

Comment: Here the main background image and the footer image is viewable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [CSS Flexboxes](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#center). Please see my code below. Note that the magic is in the CSS for #img2Container. Also, see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dymoo9k/).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #img1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #img2Container {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;

                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-direction: row;
                flex-direction: row;
                -webkit-justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            #img2 {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" />
        <div id="img2Container">
            <img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's reasonable to believe that you could also wrap the image in another element and use margin: 0 auto. However, I like this method better because of the flexibility of CSS Flexboxes, allowing you to center more than one image and have them all centred evenly.

Please note that the img2Container has position absolute, which means that it scrolls with the page. If you would prefer, you could set it to sticky so that the remains in the viewing pane and positions it to the viewpane rather than the document.